# Banach's Fixed Point theorem - banach vector space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

> **Problem 1** (Banach fixed point theorem). Let $(V, || \, \, \, ||)$ be a Banach space, $U \subset V$ a *closed* subset (in the sense that convergent sequences in $U$ have their limits in $U$) and $T : U \rightarrow U$ a map which is distance decreasing, i.e., for all $x,y \in U$ we have \begin{align}||T(x)-T(y)|| \le c||x-y||, & \text{for some } 0 \le c < 1. \end{align}
>   Such maps are called *contractions*. Show that any such map has a unique fixed point in $U$, that is, there is exactly one point $f_0 \in U$ such that $T(f_0)=f_0$.

I would love any help on this problem.

Comment: **Theorem:** Theorems that have names are proved in the books.

Comment: what book is this>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U$ is closed in $V$ (which is complete), then $U$ must be $\mathbf{complete}$( this is the key fact in the solution to this problem). Suppose $U \neq \varnothing$. Hence, there exists $u_0 \in U$. We define a sequence as follows:

$u_1 = T u_0 $

$u_2 = T u_1 = T^2 u_0 
$

...

$u_m  = T^m u_0  $

Next, we show $(u_m) $ is complete. First of all, notice

$$ ||u_{m+1} - u_m || = ||T u_m - T u_{m-1} || \leq c || u_m - u_{m-1} || \leq ... \leq c^m ||u_1 - u_0||$$

Hence, for $n > m $, we have (by triangle inequality)

$$ ||u_m - u_n || \leq ||u_m - u_{m+1} || + || u_{m+1} - u_{m+2} || + ... + |u_{n-1} - u_n || \leq (c^m + c^{m+1} + ... + c^{n-1} ) ||u_1 - u_0 || =_{why?} c^m \frac{1 - c^{n-m}}{1-c} ||u_1-u_0|| < \frac{c^m}{1-c} ||u_1 - u_0 ||$$

Notice, you can make the last expression as small as you want. You should verify this. This implies that $(u_m)$ is a cauchy sequence. Since $U$ is complete, there exists $u \in U$ such that $u_m \to u $. Now, I leave it to you to show that $u$ is the fixed point and is unique.

Added: To show $u$ is indeed the fixed point, we use the triangle inequality:

$$ ||Tu -u||  \leq ||Tu - u_n || + ||u_n - u || = ||Tu - T u_{n-1} || + ||u_n - u || < c||u - u_{n-1} || + ||u_n - u|| < c \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \to 0$$

This we can do since $(x_n)$ is cauchy. Hence

$$ ||Tu - u || = 0 $$

which implies $Tu = u$

Comment: 1-c is always negative though, is that a problem?

Comment: nope because $c^m \to 0 $

Comment: Thanks a lot. do you have any tips for showing it IS the fixed point once I have the limit? I think I can show uniqueness.

Comment: I have added details. Hope it helps!